# Trying to find column/row headers on a screen that contains multiple tables

Tags: javascript, testing, automated-tests, e2e-testing, testcafe

So my scenario is:

I have 2 tables on a screen, table 1 has certain data in it.

I want to assert that in each table the correct column & row headings exist.

So far what I have tried is: -

```
.expect(page.Table.nth(0).page.tableHeaderRow.nth(1).withText('row heading').exists).ok()
```

However when I try this I get the following 2 errors: -

> 1) A call to an async function is not awaited. Use the "await" keyword before actions, assertions or chains of
>         them to ensure that they run in the right sequence.
>
> 2) TypeError: Cannot read property 'tableHeaderRow' of undefined

I get that the above code I've written may be totally incorrect but how would I go about finding the row/column header in table 1 only?

Comment: 1. Make sure that you added the "await" keyword: https://devexpress.github.io/testcafe/documentation/test-api/test-code-structure.html#test-controller

Comment: 2. Use specific TestCafe Selectors to find the required element (e.g. the ID, class or DOM Selector based on your markup): https://devexpress.github.io/testcafe/documentation/test-api/selecting-page-elements/selectors/

Answer (score 0):

As Marion mentioned, make sure that you added the "[await](https://devexpress.github.io/testcafe/documentation/test-api/test-code-structure.html#test-controller)" keyword. In addition, you can use specific TestCafe Selectors to find the required element (e.g. the ID, class or DOM Selector based on your markup) as described in the [Selectors](https://devexpress.github.io/testcafe/documentation/test-api/selecting-page-elements/selectors/) topic.